# C++ multi-threading and copied objects

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm working on a multi-threaded monte carlo simulation as part of a course in computational finance. I've implemented a thread pool class and a concurrent queue class, which i've verified are working as intended, by doing a multi-threaded matrix multiplication example. However, i'm also doing monte carlo simulation, where i've implemented a random number generator that skips ahead in the number generation (to produce same results with single-threaded and multi-threaded calculation).

Code for monte carlo (not working, not 4 times faster with 4 cores):

```
double mcProduct::mtPricer() {

vector<double> res;
res.resize(nPath);

threadPool pool;            // Threadpool
vector<taskHandle> futs;    // handles
ranGen ran;                 // Random number generator class
size_t firstPath = 0;

while (firstPath < nPath)
{
    size_t lastPath = firstPath + pathsPrTask;
    if (lastPath > nPath) lastPath = nPath;

    futs.push_back(pool.submitTask(
        [&, firstPath, lastPath]()
    {
        ranGen lran;
        lran = ran;     // Clone number generator using copy constructor
        lran.skipAhead(firstPath);  

        for (size_t i = firstPath; i < lastPath; ++i)
        {
            const double st = applySDE(invNormalCdf(lran.nextU()));
            res[i] = exp(-rate*mat)*mymax<double>(st - strike, 0.0);
        }
        return true;
    }));
    firstPath = lastPath;
}

// Wait for threads to complete
for_each(futs.begin(), futs.end(), mem_fn(&taskHandle::wait));
return vMean(res);
}
```

Code for matrix multiplication (working, roughly 4 times faster)

```
double mcProduct::matrixMult() {

threadPool pool;            // Threadpool
vector<taskHandle> futs;    // handles
size_t firstPath = 0;

while (firstPath < nPath)
{
    size_t lastPath = firstPath + pathsPrTask;
    if (lastPath > nPath) lastPath = nPath;

    futs.push_back(pool.submitTask(
        [&, firstPath, lastPath]()
    {

        for (size_t i = firstPath; i < lastPath; ++i)
        {
             multAMatrix(); // Matrix multiplication void (30x30)
        }
        return true;
    }));
    firstPath = lastPath;
}

// Wait for threads to complete
for_each(futs.begin(), futs.end(), mem_fn(&taskHandle::wait));
return 0.0;
}
```

So basically, the difference between the two implementations is that i copy the ranGen class instance for each task-assignment (the submitTask callable in the lambda). At first, i thought that the skipping ahead might be slow, but that is not the case. The problem seems to be with this "lran.nextU()" implementation, which iterates the random number generation by 1 step (i.e. produces a new random number). I've been thinking that this might have something to do with false sharing or cache misses, but i'm kind of out of ideas. My intention is not to share anything between the objects. I just want a clean copy of the random number generator!

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It’s hard to solve this without a framework to test it in. In any case, have you tried omitting the ``&`` from the lambda capture and explicitly capturing the random number generator by copy? Also, maybe you could try using separate result vectors for the individual threads (even though I suspect that the cache interference here should be minimal). Also, I assume you are sure that applySDE and invNormalCdf do not do any locking.

Comment: Locking should not be a problem in this case. I've tried to the applySDE calculation explicitly within the lambda. This does not change anything, so i don't think it's a problem. The "lran.nextU" does a 3x3 * 3x1 matrix multiplication. I've been wondering if the work done within the lambda "is too little" for multithreading to have a real effect. This could explain why, doing a 30x30 matrix multiplication within each step gives correct results